# How to retrieve system proxy settings in Win 7 for windows service in C

Tags: c, windows, service, proxy, wininet

I am writing an application that will run as a service and will pick system proxy settings for communication with the outside world .I tried  `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser` but it fails to retrieve proxy settings for current user which is obvious since service is running under the domain of Local System. To realize the same I have to made the user to logon to the service which I don't want application user to do. I read about `SERVICE_USER_OWN_PROCESS` parameter which can be passed to CreateService() but neither I found its declaration in WinNT.h nor I am sure if it will work. Development of application is stuck because of this issue. Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation with running a program in the context of the current user.

First of all - somewhere in a global scope - define following variables:

```
 HANDLE hUsrToken;
 HANDLE hDupToken;
 int sessionId;
```

You need to get the session Id of the current user:

```
int getInteractiveSessinoId()
{
    PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessInfo;
    ulong count;                    // Number of current user sessions
    int result = -1;

    if (!WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, 0, 1, &pSessInfo, &count))
    {
        printf("Getting session information failed with error %d\n", << GetLastError());
        WTSFreeMemory(pSessInfo);
        return -2;
    }

    for (ulong loop = 0; loop < count; loop++)
    {
        if (pSessInfo[loop].State == WTSActive)
        {
            printf("Session %d is currently active\n", pSessInfo[loop].SessionId);
            result = pSessInfo[loop].SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    WTSFreeMemory(pSessInfo);
    return result;
}
```

Next you need to impersonate the current user (I called it "attach to the session"):

```
bool attachToSession(int sessionId)
{
    // We need to duplicate the token of the session's user
    if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &hUsrToken))
    {
        pritnf("Query the user token failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hUsrToken, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation , &hDupToken))
    {
        printf("Duplicating a token failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hDupToken))
    {
        printf("Impersonating the user failed with error %d\n", GetLastError();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now do whatever you want to do want to do within the current user's context, when done, revert (or "detach") from the user's context:

```
bool detachFromSession()
{
    if (!RevertToSelf())
    {
        printf("Reverting the token failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    (void)CloseHandle(hDupToken);
    (void)CloseHandle(hUsrToken);

    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure if it is good idea to apply the token to the current (service) thread. I think it is a better idea to create a new thread which executes whatever you want to do in the user's context and apply the impersonated token to it. So your code part may look like this:

```
HANDLE hUsrToken;
HANDLE hDupToken;
HANDLE hThread;
int sessionId;
DWORD threadId;

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(...
}

sessionId = getInterActiveSessionId();

if (attachToSession(int sessionId) == false)
{
    // Error handling
    return;
}

hThread = CreateThread(NULL,                   // default security attributes
                       0,                      // use default stack size                       
                       MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
                       NULL,                   // argument to thread function 
                       CREATE_SUSPENDED,       // Delay execution
                       &threadId);

if (SetThreadToken(hThread, hDupToken) == false)
{
    // Error handling
    return;
}

ResumeThread(hThread);
```

I cannot garantee that this will resolve your problem, but I hope it does. Good luck!

Comment: What will be the behavior of service when impersonate API is called with no user logged on to system yet?

Comment: getInteractiveSessinoId() in the code above will return with an invalid id (returns -2) which should be handled properly. Otherwise attachToSession() will fail in WTSQueryUserToken() will return with error which is handled in the function.

In short words: It is up to to ensure that you have an interactive session.
Attaching to session 0 (where services are running) does not make sense since you are already running in that session.